# How to create flavor in openstack using python code

Tags: python, openstack

Can anyone please tell me how to create flavor. I have a code format given below  but I don't know how to create a openstack flavor using below python code?

```
def create_flavor(self,**attrs)
    .....
    .....
    return self._create(_flavor.Flavor,**attrs)
```

Comment: Please add more details. What have you tried yet? Show us some code.

Comment: We are created connection...ofter dat we are trying to launch instance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nova client to create a flavor as in below code sample:

```
from keystoneauth1 import loading
from keystoneauth1 import session
from novaclient import client

AUTH_URL = 'http://10.10.10.200:35357/v3'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'password'
PROJECT_NAME = 'admin'
USER_DOMAIN_NAME = 'Default'
PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME = 'Default'

loader = loading.get_plugin_loader('password')
auth = loader.load_from_options(auth_url=AUTH_URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, project_name=PROJECT_NAME, user_domain_name=USER_DOMAIN_NAME, project_domain_name=PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME)
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
nova = client.Client(NOVA_API_VERSION, session=sess)


def create_flavor(name, ram, vcpus, disk):
    nova.flavors.create(name=name, ram=ram, vcpus=vcpus, disk=disk)

# Call the function to create flavor    
create_flavor('test', 1024, 1, 10)

# Call help on flavor create function to know all the parameters the function accepts
help(nova.flavors.create)
```

You can use requests library to create a flavor as in below sample code.
You have to replace the endpoint IP, admin tenant id, token id , etc

```
import json
import requests


def create_flavor():
    url = 'http://10.26.12.31:8774/v2.1/5a56b817ec7342a9a6c0eea26f591621/flavors'
    token = 'gAAAAABZY1-p4Sb24NXsGGEAPG9Sg_cjDIGs2TUeBt5V256sU0sapnzAnLKkgLkY8cAVz1DfoKYKP7Yct6xcGqojm49ssWnPNoJTZ7AvZqECvXYXeS-xZB5Zjk22TIoo_WFnLXimMf3xmT04zkJVDZqSxc1jGzM21KQXKbAWXCi6NDbeKgqSgXw'

    headers = {'X-Auth-Token': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    flavor_details= {'flavor': {'name':'test','ram':1024,'vcpus':2,'disk':10}}

    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(flavor_details),headers=headers)
    print response

create_flavor()
```

Comment: I need complete python program

Comment: Without using nova

Comment: Check the updated answer and upvote/accept the answer if it works fine.